# Regex start and end with specific char, then exclude string between

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude a specific string from a url link between two characters. In this case variable ***test***. Then end on first **"** character.

```
<a href="/?q=test&parameter1&parameter2" ...more content
```

So far I built this Regex expression:

```
(?<=[?]q=)[^"]*
```

[TEST](https://regex101.com/r/LZIy15/1)

Required result:

<a href="/?q=test **&parameter1&parameter2** " ...more content

Thank you!

Comment: You can replace the match with an empty string.

Comment: Would the text you need to exclude always be right after your positive look behind?

Comment: Yes. It will be always at the same position.

Comment: So would [`\?q=[^&]+(&[^"]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/nOS7sF/1) work for you where you grab the 1st capture groups's content?

Comment: Absolutely. Now I wondering, how to use that group with matchAll and replace all occurrences with empty string.

Comment: Wait, do you want something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/eG1dQz/1)? Replacing `(\?q=[^&]*)&[^"]*` with `$1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(\?q=[^&]*)&[^"]*
```

and replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eG1dQz/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%5C%3Fq%3D%5B%5E%26%5D*)%26%5B%5E%22%5D*):

[image]

*Details*

- `(\?q=[^&]*)` - Capturing group 1: `?q=` text and then any zer or more chars other than `&`
- `&` - a literal `&` char
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than a `"`.

Answer (score 2):

Use look arounds to match *between* `test` and `"`, where `test` is a whole word (eg not `testing`) and is a query param (preceded by `=` or `&`, so order of params doesn’t matter):

```
(?<=[=&]test\b).*?(?=")
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/U9yMP2AUIXA2ri).

Then use your (unspecified) language/tool to replace matches with blank.

To match *everything* not `test` in params, ie other params preceding *or* following`test` too:

```
(?<=q=).*?(?=\btest\b)|(?<=[=&]test\b).*?(?=")
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ZbtkLEskv8bDJS).